# Understanding partition elimination

Tags: sql-server, performance, partitioning, query-performance

I am trying to understand the below query being run from our developers on read only database which just runs forever.

Table here is partitioned table on partition column trickey per day.

Query is something like below

```
Select 
   a,
   b,
   c,
   d,
   trickey 
from 
   table 
where 
   (1=1) 
   and (1=1) and convert(varchar(10),trickey,112) BETWEEN 20190913 and 20190913
```

Will above query not eligible for partition key elimination OR how can i improve or tune up the above query?

Also what is the benefit of (1=1 )used in where clause and does that help or degrade performance?

@Justin- Modified query

```
Select 
       a,
       b,
       c,
       d,
       trickey 
    from 
       table 
    where 
       (1=1) 
       and (1=1) ---and convert(varchar(10),trickey,112) BETWEEN 20190913 and 20190913 replace this one with modified version

and trickey>=cast('2019-09-13' as date)
and trickey< cast('2019-09-14' as date)
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to get the [estimated query plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/display-the-estimated-execution-plan?view=sql-server-2017) in SSMS without running the query.

If you do, you'll see that SQL Server is not going to be able to use partition elimination because you have a function on the partitioning column.  Just like using a function on an indexed column prevents SQL Server from using the index, using a function on a partitioning column prevents SQL Server from doing partition elimination.  SQL Server has no idea how to prove which partition `function( column )` data might be in so it has to scan all of them.

Assuming `trickey` is a `datetime` column, you likely just want to compare it against dates directly rather than using a function

```
and trickey >= cast( '2019-09-13' as date ) 
and trickey <  cast( '2019-09-14' as date )
```

Comment: Your answer is likely correct, but estimated plans don't show partition elimination. See [here](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SJmMUmgwB) vs. [here](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rJoGI7lDB).

Comment: @ErikDarling, My bad. I did not intended to do so. Later when i try to edit the option went away. I should delete it probably  and check again.

Comment: @justin - i modified the code as mentioned for where clause and query returned 0 rows with execution plan showing as constant scan. So it seems changing that does not wo

Comment: @BeginnerDBA - Is `trickey` a `datetime` column?  And are you sure that it has data where the value is between those two dates

Comment: @JustinCave: Yes thats correct, trickey is a datetime column [PK] and yes data is there

Comment: @BeginnerDBA - How do you know that there is data in the table where `trickey` is between 2019-09-13 and 2019-09-14 if the query returns 0 rows for that predicate?  I suppose it's possible that you've encountered a tremendous bug in SQL Server that needs to be reported to Microsoft but it's much more likely that there is no data that matches the criteria you specified.  Either because the data isn't what you expect or because the criteria in your query isn't correct.

Comment: @JustinCave: i checked for the number of rows in that partition boundary range  and it showed over 20 Million rows out there

Comment: Used the script from https://dbafromthecold.com/2014/06/04/partitioning-basics-part-1/ to check rows in each partitions. We have total of 1373 with right boundary value for each day and as checked i can see data in that specific partition of 2019-09-13

Comment: @BeginnerDBA - That script tells you the statistics on the partition.  That doesn’t necessarily match the number of rows in the partition.  If there is actually data in the partition between the two dates, I’d expect that you have an error in your Urey.  Can you post a reproducible test case that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: @JustinCave, i also see the same row count when checked from GUI- right click table->storage-> Manage compression and see the rows for that partition. If that's not correct then how can i check for same?

Comment: @BeginnerDBA - Again, that's just statistics which may or may not match what is really in the table.  You'd need to run a query against the table to see how many rows are actually in the partition.  You say you are doing that and getting 0 rows which implies that that partition doesn't have any data in that range.  You could potentially use the $PARTITION syntax to query that specific partition https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/partition-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-2017 to see what it actually contains if anything.

Comment: i did - select count(*) from table where $partition.pfname(trickey)=1200, it returns over 20 M rows and then 1200 part number is for the date we are searching

Comment: @BeginnerDBA - And what is the query you are running that returns 0 rows?

Comment: @JustinCave- pasted in question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98860/discussion-between-justin-cave-and-beginnerdba).